# Validar un Select en AngulatJS

Tags: angularjs

Necesito validar 3 select con el mismo arreglo de datos, pero los select no deben de tener la misma información, espero explicarme... les dejo el código:

```
<select ng-model= "frmData.cena1" 
        ng-options= "cena as cena.nombre for cena in cenas track by cena.id" 
        class= "form-control">
    <option value="">--Elige el cena principal--</option>
</select>
<br>
<select ng-model= "frmData.cena2" 
        ng-options="cena as cena.nombre for cena in cenas track by cena.id" 
        class= "form-control">
     <option value="">--Elige el cena 1--</option>
 </select>
 <br>    
 <select ng-model= "frmData.cena3" 
         ng-options= "cena as cena.nombre for cena in cenas track by cena.id" 
         class= "form-control">
     <option value="">--Elige el cena 2--</option>
 </select>`
```

Como ven los select son llenados del mismo arreglo, solo necesito que no se pueda ser el mismo seleccionado en ninguno de los 3

Answer (score 0):

te pongo el codigo de como creo que tienes que hacer los selects, no as puesto el JS tampoco se muy bien como traes los datos. Prueba y me comentas. Un Saludo

```
<select ng-model="frmData.cena1" class="form-control">
<option ng-repeat="cena as cena.nombre for cena in cenas track by cena.id" ng-value="cena.codigo">{{cena.valor}}</option>
</select>

<br>

<select ng-model="frmData.cena2" class="form-control">
<option ng-repeat="cena as cena.nombre for cena in cenas track by cena.id" ng-value="cena.codigo">{{cena.valor}}</option>
</select>

<br>

<select ng-model="frmData.cena3" class="form-control">
<option ng-repeat="cena as cena.nombre for cena in cenas track by cena.id" ng-value="cena.codigo">{{cena.valor}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Intente lo que mostraste, pero no me muestra nada de información, la variable cenas, solo es un arreglo de objetos.